# Order WordPress posts by first letter in title not first number

Tags: loops, wordpress

I have a custom post type that's used to display properties on a client website. I am sorting the posts by the title but want to ignore any numbers included in that title.

so to clarify I would like to sort posts by the first letter [A-Z] not [0-9, A-Z].

This is my current loop.

```
<section id="grid" class="project clearfix">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul id="project" class="clearfix">

<?php
// select our project post types
$wptricckspost = array( 'post_type' => 'project',
                        'orderby'=> 'title', 
                        'order' => 'ASC' );
// Create the new loop
$loop = new WP_Query( $wptricckspost );
?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

<li class="item">
 <header>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</header>
<article>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    // Other html stuff below...
```

If anyone could help me with an example it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

An example of how I need these to sort is.

- Air W1
- Angel Court
- Basinghall Avenue
- 1 Eagle Court
- 31 Gresham Street
- 5 Hanover Square
- Kings Quarter
- LCW...

Comment: Can you provide a few sample titles and how they'd look after sorting?

Comment: Sure, I want them to sort like this...
- Air W1
- Angel Court
- Basinghall Avenue
- 1 Eagle Court
- 31 Gresham Street
- 5 Hanover Square
- Kings Quarter
- LCW...`